# ssh command use a Matlab library

Tags: ssh, matlab

Since I installed matlab on ubuntu, when I run ssh I've got something like

```
$ ssh
ssh: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin/glnxa64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by ssh)
ssh: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin/glnxa64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by ssh)
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
           [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file] [-L address]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-Q query_option] [-R address] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] [user@]hostname [command]

$ type ssh
ssh is /usr/bin/ssh
```

What happened? How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you created an alias or function for ssh ? Pls update your question with the output of `type ssh`,

Comment: Did you define any linker-related environment variables - such as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` - or add anything to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` was linked to matlab in the environment variables. I don't remember why I added this. Probably to fix a matlab issue without understanding what I was doing. Now I know what is `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. There was also `/runtime/glnxa64` `sys/os/glnxa64` and `sys/opengl/lib/glnxa64` in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: @amarion so there's your problem - without knowing *why* you did that (AFAIK it shouldn't be necessary, in a normal MATLAB installation) it's hard to suggest the right fix - possibly wrapping the `matlab` command in a script that sets the variable only for its own environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by steeldriver I looked in `/etc/environment` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` was defined as

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/sys/os/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/sys/opengl/lib/glnxa64"
```

I commented this line and ssh is working just fine. Matlab seems to run but I didn't looked in details if everything was working.

For those like me who didn't know what was `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` it'[s a colon-separated set of directories where libraries should be searched for first](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html).